# Does Elasticsearch provide highlighting on "copy_to" field in their newer versions?

Tags: elasticsearch

I had used Elasticsearch few years ago(version 6.4.0) and they had no provision to provide highlight the "copy_to" field. I would like to know if they have this provision now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, highlight can enabled on copy_to field in latest version.

Please check below example which i have tried.

Index Mapping:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "first_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "full_name" 
      },
      "last_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "full_name" 
      },
      "full_name": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Document Index:

```
PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Smith"
}
```

Query:

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "full_name": {
        "query": "John Smith",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "full_name": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my-index-000001",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.5753642,
        "_source" : {
          "first_name" : "John",
          "last_name" : "Smith"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "full_name" : [
            "<em>Smith</em>",
            "<em>John</em>"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1: Search using copy_to field and highlight match to particular field**
In below example, search will be happen on full_name field which is copy field and highlight will be happen on first_name field.
Query:

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "full_name": {
        "query": "John Smith",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "require_field_match": "false", 
    "fields": {
      "first_name": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
        "_index" : "my-index-000001",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.5753642,
        "_source" : {
          "first_name" : "John",
          "last_name" : "Smith"
        },
        "highlight" : {
          "first_name" : [
            "<em>John</em>"
          ]
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way to disable highlighting on this copy_to field? I would like to search using copy_to field but highlight the match on a particular field and not the copy_to field

Comment: @MNikesh yes, you can achived this using "require_field_match": "false" parameter in highlight. I have updtaed my answer with this paramater.